# De manière claire, qu'est-ce qu'on peut comprendre de ce passage ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Qu'est-ce qu'on peut comprendre de ce passage ?

> Et la parole dénaturée dans tous ces mots, qui s’accumulent, s’échangent, restera muette oui, qu’elle reste muette, avant de retrouver dans une parole lancée à quelqu’un sa nécessité rageuse, retrouve son poids, sa valeur, qui n’est pas celle d’échange, de l’un à l’autre, comme un aller retour qui irait de soi. Vous sentez vous vous éloigner dans la parole qui vient à ce moment là, simple masse sonore chargée tout à coup de sens, dans une réflexion rêveuse .

Eugène Durif.

Comment: Pour la prochaine fois, à mon avis il serait préférable de préciser un peu la question et de montrer un travail de recherche, en expliquant ce que tu as compris par exemple. Je suis aussi nouveau ici (mais habitué de ce genre d'entraide, sur les canaux IRC en particulier), voilà pourquoi j'ai tout de même répondu, pour cette fois.

Comment: Ce site est un [site de questions-réponses](/tour), pas un forum de discussion. Une question doit avoir un objectif précis. Une explication de texte portant sur un paragraphe complet, c'est trop. Si un point particulier vous pose problème, éditez votre message pour poser une question sur ce point en particulier.

Answer (score 1):

De manière concise et globale, je pense qu'ici la personne évoque le fait de "parler pour ne rien dire", des échanges sans fonds et pauvres de sens jusqu'à ce que le dialogue reprenne vie, qu'il retrouve un vrai sens et une certaine utilité. Les mots sont alors plus que des mots, en effet, quand ils sont bien choisis ils ont une portée parfois même au delà de nos propres attentes. C'est la beauté du verbe, n'est-ce pas ? ;)