# Sens de « de main en main »

Tags: sens, expressions

Dans ce passage, que veut dire l'expression « de main en main » ?

> Qu’est-ce que la parole si ce n’est ce qui serait pris directement dans une idée de communication, mais où il y aurait forcément de la communication avec quelque chose qui se passe de main en main. Mallarmé en parle quand il dit quelque chose comme, une pièce sans envers ni endroit que l’on se passe de main en main en silence.

Comment: C'est dommage que vous n'ayiez pas pris en compte le commentaire à votre précédente question : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/36653/de-mani%c3%a8re-claire-quest-ce-quon-peut-comprendre-de-ce-passage  Je ne peux que le réitérer

Comment: En plus ça fait des titres génériques inutiles plutôt que de présenter ce dont il est question. On peut inférer de la réponse que _de main en main_ devrait probablement apparaître au titre.

Comment: Comme l'ont déjà signalé d'autres commentateurs, ce site est un [site de questions-réponses](/tour), pas un forum de discussion. Une question doit avoir un objectif précis, par exemple le sens d'une expression dans un contexte particulier. Une explication de texte portant sur un paragraphe complet, c'est trop.

Answer (score 2):

*[De main en main](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/de_main_en_main)* est une locution adverbiale courante. Elle signifie que dans une groupe, un objet tenu en main est transmis successivement par chaque personne à la suivante. La locution est utilisée ici au sens figuré puisque la parole ne circule pas de main en main, mais de [bouche à oreille](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bouche_%C3%A0_oreille).

Cette image permet de produire un effet de style, un *paradoxisme* : la parole se propage en silence...

Comment: Oui et +1 avec le fait que, sans que je sache dire pourquoi,  le *bouche à oreille* donne plus une idée de restriction à la communication que le main en main.